# Marquee/Scrolling text for my webpage

Tags: jquery, scroll

I got an autoscroller- a jQuery code to make text scroll from [here](http://www.yeesiang.com/jquery.autoScroller/).

I have to make 2 marquee contents in my html webpage.

I used the same code content as available in the page and made a testing page.The test page works fine.

I used the same code in my page and tried. but it doesnt work online. It works when I test my page offline. Any ideas what the problem could be? I need suggestions. Please help.

Does the order of placing the javascript pages on the head section have anything to do with it?

**This is my head section:**

```
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.css" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link href="slide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timers.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autoScroller.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){     

      g_globalObject = new JsDatePick({
        useMode:1,
        isStripped:true,
        target:"calendar"
      });

      g_globalObject.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
        var obj = g_globalObject.getSelectedDay();
        alert("Selected date is : " + obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year);
        document.getElementById("calendar_result").innerHTML = obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year;
      });   

      g_globalObject2 = new JsDatePick({
        useMode:1,
        isStripped:false,
        target:"div4_example",
        cellColorScheme:"beige"
      });

      g_globalObject2.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
        var obj = g_globalObject2.getSelectedDay();
        alert("Selected date is : " + obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year);
        document.getElementById("calendar_result").innerHTML = obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year;
      });   
    };
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
      .style1 {
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: If you create a JSFiddle for this post, that will more help to understand the code. Otherwise every one has to create the same stuff at their on local machine. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes, the order of the js pages in the head section matters, because  there are lot of api`s which depend on the jquery lib, so it is good practice to keep jquery lib first in the order. in your case ,are u getting any specific error message over console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of yes it matters what order put your javascript files in. For example if you want to use jQuery you have to link to that first, before you link to a jQuery component and you should not use 2 different versions of it. you are linking to js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js and jquery-1.3.2.min.js .. stick to one.

Have you tried comparing the source code? Since you say it works fine one place, and not another there is probably something different there.